# Is [advanced] a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Because [Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) are now discouraged on SE sites, I don't think that the [advanced](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced) tag is a good tag.

I think it is a meta tag, because:

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.

It can't work as the only tag. It needs other tags, such as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) ...

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

The [advanced](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced) means something else for different people: person A can find a challenge an advanced challenge, while person B can find it a intermediate challenge.

Should the tag be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that that tag adds no value whatsoever. To my understanding, [moderators can't delete a tag directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124504/13), so I have put a request for a staff member to go take care of it.